# Modules not found when trying to use a new Configuration in a project with multiple Frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have multiple frameworks for different modules of my application:

[image]

I'm trying to create multiple targets, each one using a different configuration (development, stage, production). But if I use different configurations when I try to compile with using them, I got errors describing that I don't have some libraries that I actually have (I'm using CocoaPods, and after create the configurations I ran the pod install again, I also tried to deintegrate and install again).

[image]

The current configurations on the Application is:

[image]

Using Debug or Release I have no errors, but If I try to use a new configuration I get the errors. There's some extra configuration that must to be applied in this specific scenario, where I have multiple targets on my project?

PS: This is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '11.1'

use_frameworks!

workspace 'xxx-app-ios'

def materialdesign_pods
  pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields'
  pod 'MaterialComponents/BottomSheet'
  pod 'MaterialComponents/Ink'
  pod 'MaterialComponents/ActivityIndicator'
  pod 'MaterialComponents/Snackbar'
  pod 'MaterialComponents/Buttons'
end

def presentation_pods
    pod 'RxCocoa'
    pod 'RxKeyboard'
    pod 'RxDataSources'
    pod 'RxSwift'
    pod 'SnapKit'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
    materialdesign_pods
end

target 'PresentationKit' do
    project 'Modules/PresentationKit/PresentationKit.project'
    presentation_pods
end

def data_pods
    pod 'Moya/RxSwift'
    pod 'KeychainAccess'
    pod 'RxSwift'
    pod 'QueryKit'
end

target 'Data' do
    project 'Modules/Data/Data.project'
    data_pods
end

def domain_pods
    pod 'RxDataSources'
    pod 'SwiftJWT'
end

target 'Domain' do
    project 'Modules/Domain/Domain.project'
    domain_pods
end

def ui_components_pods
    pod 'BEMCheckBox'
    pod 'MBRadioCheckboxButton'
    pod 'RxCocoa'
    pod 'RxSwift'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
```